# Windows batch. Put Serial port data in a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, console, serial-port

I have a hardware (battery controller) that send battery voltage over a serial port. It's just 4-digit value+endline ('1232\r\n') every 5 seconds.
I need to read that value and if it's below a treshold shut PC down. It's old WinXP machine where I'm allowed to use CMD only without creating temporary files.

On my home PC I created a test environment with two virtual ports (with com2com utility) and powershell script that emulates hardware:

```
cls
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
$port.PortName = "COM4"
$port.open()
while (1) {
$port.Write("1000"+[char]13+[char]10)
$port.close()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
$port.open()
}
```

Script below has to recieve data and shut down PC if value below treshold. But it doesn't work.

```
@ ECHO OFF
MODE COM5 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 > nul
set tr=1100
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`TYPE COM5`) DO set x=%%i
IF %x% lss %tr% (ECHO System will shutdown
rem shutdown /s
)
```

When I run script It's just waits endlessly.

Comment: Does the hardware send only the four characters (digits) you mentioned, or is there also a `CR`, `LF` or `CRLF`?

Comment: @Stephan Digits + CRLF, like in my powershell script

Comment: Does it send it to `COM5`? or `COM4` like in your PowerShell script.

Comment: @Compo: COM4 as sender, COM5 as receiver. The mentioned utility creates two virtual ports, connected with a virtual cable. Works, when using putty as a receiver, so the sender.ps1 is confirmed to work as expected. `copy com2: con:` also works as receiver, so the virtual connection itself is confirmed to work too.

Answer (score 0):

The `for /f` loop does not output the results of the command line-by-line as received. It waits for the command to complete so, by using `type COM5` you will have a running command that does not exit, unless it experiences EOF.
To do this you can redirect its output as input to the `for` loop

```
<COM5 (for /L %%i in (0) do set x=%%i)
```

You have to note though that this will not run as a permanent loop and you'll have to create a permanent loop if you plan on running it continually.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've made a small test script: 
`@ ECHO OFF
MODE COM5 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 > nul
:start
ECHO Listen port
<COM5 (for /L %%i in (0) do set x=%%i)
ECHO x=%x%
TIMEOUT /t 1 /nobreak
GOTO start
`

It still waits endlessly on `<COM5 (for /L %%i in (0) do set x=%%i)` line